# Stop resizing border on jQueryUI size effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, border, effects

I am executing a simple jQueryUI "size" effect.

```
myElement.effect( "size", { to: { height: myHeight }}, 500);
```

The problem is that the border of the element is also resized. Is there any property that stops resizing the border?

Comment: Have you got any fiddle showing us your problem? I reckon that is the normal behavior according to the CSS box model http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/ Have a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/rjHWR/1/

Comment: Sorry for not creating an example. Yours shows exactly the problem :) Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation on the size effect: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Size

There are four possible arguments / options (from, to, origin, scale).  The argument you're looking for is the scale argument.  By default, it's set to "both".  You want to set it to "content"..

```
myElement.effect( "size", { to: { height: myHeight }, scale: "content"}, 500);​​​​​​​​
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rjHWR/2/

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the property I was looking for.